# Change owner on its own directory

Tags: linux, permissions, chown

I have a script running with the user `user1:user1`, making operations inside a directory `dir`.
At the end of the script, I would like to use chown to change the owner of the script to `user2:user2`

But it doesn't work. I tried the same operation, logged in as user1 :

```
$ ls -l
drwxr-xr-x 5 user1 user1 4096 Jan 11 10:58 dir
$ chown -R user2:user2 dir
chown: changing ownership of dir: Operation not permitted
```

Why can't I change the owner of my own files/repertories ?
Is there an other way than using a root access to do this ?

UPDATE

The script makes a git clone and then a rsync with an Apache directory. New files have for owner the current user, but I need Apache to be the owner instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [chown - Operation not permitted](http://superuser.com/questions/697608/chown-operation-not-permitted)

Comment: Also relevant: [Why can't a normal user `chown` a file?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/27350/2465) on [unix.se]

Comment: It seems to me to be a rather *elementary* security measure: if it did not exist, I could transfer ownership of infected files to other users at will.

Answer (score 1):

The `chown` command is only available for `root`, for security reasons, so if you want to do that, you'll have to do it as root.

There are 2 things that come to my mind that you can do:

- Use the `SETUID` bit. This way, you're allowing users to run the script as `root` (though it also has security concerns, depending on what your script does). More on this [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid).
- You might also create a task-based queue (for example, using [redis](http://redis.io)). The script would insert a value on the queue when run, and a script run as `root` would read that queue and make any needed changes (in your case, use `chown` on that file).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have updated my post with the detail of the script. I tried to do `chmod u+s script`, but it doesn't change anything. Is this the right way to use it ?

Comment: You running the script as root?  If not that's why it's doing nothing

Comment: You'd need to change ownership to `root`. When run as non-root, effectively it will be run as `root` instead of the user that invoked the script.